# xcode simulator crashing xcode when trying to run app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I was propted by apple to upgrade my debugger settings yesterday, In doing so I have some how broken xcode.

When ever I now try to load an application (dosn't matter what version of the simulator I am using) Xcode and my simulator both freeze up. then the rainbow loader just sits their constantly turning over.

Is there any way to fix this? I'm really stuck and don't know what to do as it dose not seem like a very common problem from all the research I have done to fix this.

I am running the latest version of xcode 4.3.2 (4E2002) and using 5.1 simulator.. and have tried 4.2 simulator to the same effect.

any help in getting my xcode back up and running would be massively appreciated.

Comment: This was happening to me a while ago, but with earlier versions. I fixed it by opening the iOS Simulator, and clicking Reset Content and Settings from the iOS Simulator drop down menu. Then I reset my computer, ran a project, and everything ran fine. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: well this is weird.. I got it to run once.. then it started doing the same thing... but even when it run that one time it didnt start the app I had to select the icon it made then it ran... so not really working still..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so I figured out what the problem is but not a real solution...

Basically the error started happening when I was prompted by xcode to update my debugger to the LLDB version. this is what cause my simulator to keep crashing xcode.. or vice versa honastly I still dont know why this is happening but yea...

so.. what I did to get this simulator working again was go to Product>edit scheme> debugger then changed from LLDB back to GDB.. this solved my issue for now... however I need to  figure out why LLDB is not working and what I should do leading into the future. hope this helps someone else.

Comment: brilliant! saved me lots of trouble

Comment: Same Problem with me too, I am using Xcode 5.1.1. I also want to know why LLDB is not working. Please reply if you know something about this

Answer (score 0):

I have facing this problem too but I got a solution either you said its temporary ... some time ios 5.1 simulator hangs when I shifted to the ios 4.1 sdk its a common practice for the developer to check it I have simply first close the simulator and again start it and then reset all the content in the preference area that its resolved my issue .. check it might be you also got resolve for apply this trick or technique.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case, was too many old breakpoints tracks (788), even to deleted files, I just clean it and now it runs perfect, I hope it helps.

A picture to illustrate:

[image]