# Opens the splashscreen then shuts down IOS Delphi XE8

Tags: ios, xcode, delphi, delphi-xe8

Good morning,

I have installed Delphi XE8 on my computer with windows 7 X64, also I have a virtual machine with virtualbox with Yosemite (10.10) also I have the paserver 16.0 and Xcode version 6.3.1 (6S1002), the problem is that when I compiling with IOS simulator 8.3, does not work, get to compile perfectly but opens the splashscreen and then shuts down.

I tried to reinstall xcode reinstall Mac, but everything remains the same.

Comment: see the time man. its 5.48 how it is Morning.

Comment: @ Ashok Londhe not everywhere

Comment: Have you applied the iOS 8 Simulator Hotfix?  [Blog Article](http://community.embarcadero.com/index.php/blogs/entry/ios-8-simulator-hotfix-beta-for-delphi-and-rad-studio-xe8-is-available-in-registered-user-downloads) [Code Central](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/30221)

Comment: Try to set paserver in verbose mode (press r  then enter), this might give some relevant information about what goes wrong.

Comment: Exactly the same problem here, and has nothing to do with PAServer - it deploys fine, but even when opening from the iPad itself it instantly crashes. I've tried to set breakpoints within the `System` unit during initialization, but it crashes well before initialization. This is with a completely blank new app.

Answer (score -1):

On project source I put my Application on the main thread.

```
Application.Initialize;
Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
Application.Run;
```

I also had a `TPushEvents` component which was `Autoactivate=True` by default. I changed it to false. also uncheck pushmessages from project options.

Extra: Here is 2 SO questions similar to yours which have answers

[xcode simulator crashing xcode when trying to run app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913520/xcode-simulator-crashing-xcode-when-trying-to-run-app)

[App opens then immediately closes - iphone simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313337/app-opens-then-immediately-closes-iphone-simulator)

Hope these help